# MongoDB (mongoose) - find by ObjectId returns empty result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Trying to find a document by ObjectId in mongoose. The query returns an empty result but when applying the same query in the "MongoDB Compass" - it returns the document.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

await CollectionModel.find({ "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DOCUMENT_ID)});
```

[image: MongoDB Compass]

What are the possible reasons for the issue?

Note: searching with other properties except the "_id" works fine.

Comment: can you post your schema too?

Comment: Finally found the issue. There is an issue in the schema. The _id property was declared in the schema as String which is wrong. Removed that and the query is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

your `query` in find is the `DOCUMENT_ID` is string because you add double quote

```
CollectionModel.find({ "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("DOCUMENT_ID")})
```

instead, it should just be

```
CollectionModel.find({ "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DOCUMENT_ID)})
```

also make sure you use `await`

```
await CollectionModel.find({ "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DOCUMENT_ID)})
```

`mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` is right but you can also just use the `string` just in case

```
 const DOCUMENT_ID = "614ad6b706f4d031e48b9430"
 await CollectionModel.find({ "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(DOCUMENT_ID)})
```

Comment: I updated the post. This is the same way I tried as you mentioned. @Stacks Queue

Comment: the id i wrote is just dummy. did you try just the string?  eg. `await CollectionModel.find({ _id: "614ad6b706f4d031e48b9430")})`

Comment: Yes, I tried with only the string. It didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `findById()` function and pass in the string form of the id. So:

```js
await CollectionModel.findById("The documents id")
```